# How to read minified CSS?

Tags: css

Do you know any tool for reading minified css?

I've tried W3C css validator, but it's hard to read if there are many errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does http://procssor.com/ work for you?

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Try using some IDE, like [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org), etc. They may help you in finding the errors.

NetBeans has also a feature of formatting the code, so that the code comes back to original form.

Comment: yes it is :) with time NetBeans is getting better in both Java and PHP webapp IDE, now with version 7.1 it has also added modern CSS3 and HTML5 features..

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Pretty Printer**](http://www.prettyprinter.de/)

It works for PHP, Java, C++, C, Perl, JavaScript, and CSS. There are a bunch of options for when to add new line breaks and when not to. Works pretty well. One problem is that the output code isn't in it's own box, so you can't Select All to grab it all at once easily.

Or have a look at 
[**Format CSS Online**](http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/)
More full featured beautifier for CSS exclusively. Has the ability to output as a file so you don't have to worry about copying and pasting at all.